# Can anyone help identify this statuette?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, cultural-history, art, africa

The statuette has been in my family for 3 generations now. It is presumed to be from Morocco and was brought to us before the second world war. It is damaged and it had an ivory rosary that was stolen by a fake restorer and never recovered. It has a sort of serial on its base 16-557. Appears to be made of ceramic, hand painted and with vivid colors. I do not know how old this actually is or its worth. I do not intend to sell this item. [image]

Comment: I am trying but 2mb size, i might as well draw it...

Comment: Could you not just shrink the image down in an image editor?

Comment: Well finally, i was not expecting that small size requirement...

Comment: Thanks for the patience

Comment: It's definitely **not** Moroccan. Rosaries are not very common there. Probably something Central of West African.

Comment: @Jos: Rosaries (or tasbih) *do* seem to have been pretty common in Morocco in the past according to the internet. "Nothing is more common than the measuring of  distances by the time occupied in pacing them,  reckoned by the fingering of a rosary". Dawson, Things seen in Morocco, 1904, p. 348.

Comment: @Jan - I understand that the culture of North Africa has changed drastically since decolonization, and this does seem like something that may well have been part of that change (without the French/Spanish colonizers around to push it anymore).

Comment: Here is an image of the current Morrocan king wearing superficially similar clothing (but note the hood (!) and the different direction of the stripes): https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2019/07/278785/king-mohammed-vi-ex-wife-lalla-salma-deny-rumors-of-custody-conflict/amp/

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe my comment was a bit unclear. Muslims (as well es believers of several other major religions) have things that look like a rosary and are used like a rosary. That they are also sometimes referred to as rosary does not mean that their users are Christian

Comment: So i take it as the Morocco or northern Africa origin of this to be quite belivable from all the wonderful details you people shared. What about age? Any suppositions on that? As its clear to me tgat identifying any 100% details about it is next to impossible.

Comment: I think not plausible at all that this statuette was made in Morocco (a country I know), for different reasons. Among them, there is no tradition in porcelain-making there ; moreover, say around 1940, why such a woman could be "portrayed" in such a gown in a country with very important religious traditions ? Have you explored the possibility of a Brazilian origin ?

Comment: Its a man, he's got a moustache too 

Comment: The subject is exotic, but such subjects were common enough in European art by the second half of 19th century, when colonialism was at its height. For example, you can see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A8gres_marrons_surpris_par_des_chiens or https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%A7ador_de_lleons for public sculptures in European cities about African subjects, and I'd say that exotic people has continued to be a commons subject of consumer figures for most of the 20th century. Therefore, I would search the origin of the statuette in a Western workshop.

Comment: Or another statuette of a black woman, made in 1895, in Germany: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Terra_Cotta_Figure_by_Goldscheider.jpg

Comment: Hi Pere and thank you, this is one of the closest reassembling works i've seen so far.